# Difference between bytes in memory vs content? (Intel format)

Tags: assembly

What is the exact difference between

```
mov eax, [ebx]
```

And

```
mov eax, ebx
```

The first one moves 4 bytes in memory at location `ebx` to `eax`, and the second one moves the contents of ebx into eax. What's the difference? What does this mean?

Comment: It's the difference between placing the house at 523 1st Avenue on a trailer and moving it vs just moving the characters "523 1st Avenue".

Comment: As someone taught me over 20 years ago, do you want the box, or what is in the [box]?

Answer (score 2):

```
mov eax, [ebx]
```

Equivalent (C\C++) to

```
*b = a;
```

And

```
mov eax, ebx
```

To

```
b = a;
```

The seconde statment say:

> Copy the value of a to b

And the first one say:

> Copy the value of the memory block you find in a address's

Comment: So for the first one, the memory address of ebx is put into eax register? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by value of memory block.

Comment: Not the memory address! the actual value! And it's the opposite, the value of **eax** goes to **ebx**.

Comment: And about the value of memory block part: ebx can hold either a real value i.e. `6` for example or a memory address such as `800100` for example. so the first statment say: go to the address pointed out by ebx, find out what the value you find there (let's say it's a `8`) and copy it into eax

Comment: Oh, I am doing the Intel format, not the ATT format, so it is mov destination, source. So it is moving the value of ebx into eax. And thank you for the memory block explanation. I get it now. :)